# Import of csv using Lotusscript not working as expected

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, read.csv

Trying to import a csv file into Notes with Lotusscript, and the handling of commas inside individual fields always is an issue. When a field has a comma inside it, even though that one item is surrounded with double quotes, it is still splitting it up as individual values for different fields, and then the index of that line is all out of whack.  Anyone know of a good template I can use to see how to do this differently?

I am watching in debugger and I have a single line in the csv looks like this:

**AAA010,"Mgr, Education Dept",XLM,6,2,MGR,SWD,N,Education,30000.00,35000.00,40000.00,Manages stuff,"BS in education, administration, or public administration"**

*(note the commas INSIDE the second field and the last field of this line of data)*

---

Now in agent's code, this is the relevant loop:

```
Do While Not EOF(filenum)
            'Print CStr(row)            
            Input #filenum%, jobcode,jobtitle,jobfunction,mgrlevel,eeo4cat,jobsubfunction,salaryplan,paygrade,jobfamily,minannual,midannual,maxannual,jobsummary,jobquals
                        
            If row > 1 Then         
                Set newDoc = dbCurr.CreateDocument  'Create Notes document and write values to it
                With newDoc
                    .Form = "jobcode"
                    .jobcode = jobcode
                    .jobtitle = jobtitle
                    .jobfunction = jobfunction
                    .mgrlevel = mgrlevel
                    .eeo4cat = eeo4cat
                    .jobsubfunction = jobsubfunction
                    .salaryplan = salaryplan
                    .paygrade = paygrade
                    .jobfamily = jobfamily
                    .minannual = CDbl(minannual)
                    .midannual = CDbl(midannual)
                    .maxannual = CDbl(maxannual)
                    .jobsummary = jobsummary
                    .jobquals = jobquals                                
                End With

                success = newDoc.ComputeWithForm(False, False)
                If success Then
                    Call newDoc.Save( True, False )
                    counter = counter + 1
                End If  
            End If

            row = row + 1
        Loop
```

Hopefully I can put together an answer here for future use by others having this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have an unquoted space in: Manages Stuff

According to the [documentation](https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/12.0.0/basic/LSAZ_INPUT_LB_STATEMENT.html),

> If the first character is not a double quotation mark, the next space, comma, or end-of-line character ends the string.

That could be what's messing up the parsing for you.

Comment: Richard, I will see if that makes a difference.  This csv line was created by Excel's save as csv, so that surprises me.   I may have to add code to check for spaces.   I will follow up as soon as I can try this.   All along I have had it in my head that the quotes were only going around items that themselves included the comma delimiter, so maybe I just have to change my assumption there.  Thank you.